# Is there a way to change deafult mail client in IE9?

Tags: email, gmail, email-client, internet-explorer-9, mailto

I am using IE9 on a Win7x64 OS.

I want that when I click a *mailto:* link, it should open with gmail.
Is there any way or hack for it?

**UPDATE**
Before I installed IE9, installing GTalk addressed all *mailto:* links to gmail (when setting "Open Gmail when I click on email links".
Now in IE9 it doesn't work. I assume my question is IE9 specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread [How to handle mailto: links with Gmail?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=0519ceff60782b91&hl=en) says that one needs to do two things:

1. Install Gmail Notifier with "Use Gmail for internet mailto: links",
2. Install Google toolbar with "Send with Gmail" in the Google Toolbar Options (under the More tab).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it works in Win7x64, the gmail notifier can setup the appropriate things for this to work.

Instructions: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966
Download: http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html

The download page only lists Win2K and XP but it is likely to work with newer versions too. Presumably it works by updating the relevant system registry locations, so will work for other browsers you have installed too if they take their mail configuration from the same settings.

Comment: I installed Google Talk which includes the notifier, and it notifies properly.
I checked the option "Open Gmail when I click on email links", but I get an IE error when clicking on *mailto* links.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "an error" when reporting issues.